# How do I stop getting values with GetKeyState when my program isnt the active program?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I'm making a program the uses the `GetKeyState()` function to check if a certain key is pressed. However, when the program isn't active (it's just running in the background) I am still getting values for when the keys are pressed. How could I overcome this so that I only get values when my program is active?

For one of my keys, here is the code:

```
if (GetKeyState('A') < 0)
{
    canvas [1] = colour;
}
```

Comment: Check for focus.

Comment: if you only want values when you're active you should use window messages. That's what they are for.

Comment: @Mgetz Could you provide an example please? I have only just heard of these

Comment: `if(::GetForegroundWindow() == my_window_handle) `

Comment: @SamFielding to handle window messages you have to have a window [There is a tutorial on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Without the context of this code it is hard to help. We can guess that you have a bogus loop around this code, but we can't see it. [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`GetKeyState` should only be used to check for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> etc. in response to another input message:

> An application calls GetKeyState in response to a keyboard-input message

A window/control should get most of its keyboard input from the [keyboard messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468861(v=vs.85).aspx), mainly `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_CHAR` and `WM_KEYUP`. These messages are sent to the window with the keyboard focus. Some of the common controls also allow the parent window to handle some of the input messages.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't use any other methods since I simply didn't know how, here's how I solved it for anyone else who would like to know:

I created a constant variable which was equal to the active window at the time of opening (my program is small so it opens very fast)

```
const HWND window2 = GetForegroundWindow();
```

And then I tested to see if the current active window was the same as this:

```
    HWND Window = GetForegroundWindow();
if (window2 == Window) { `**Put original code here**` }
```

it's definitely a crude way of doing it, and sure it may not work for larger programs, but if it works, it works :).